# Configure logstash with docker

Tags: kibana

I would like to configure logstash and kibana with docker any tutorial? I have search tutorials but I don't see anything.
Where I could search any information about elk?

Answer (score 0):

Two tutorials I found useful were:

- [Complete Guide for Docker Monitoring with the ELK Stack | logz.io](http://logz.io/learn/docker-monitoring-elk-stack/)
- [Running ELK stack on docker - full solution](http://www.avitzurel.com/blog/2016/06/06/running-elk-on-docker---full-solution/)

Of course, they specify how to build your own image which might not be what you're looking for. Have you tried this ELK image - [The ELK stack powered by Docker and Compose | GitHub](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) ?